# How to restart an Activity automatically after it crashes?

Tags: android, service, crash, restart

Is there a way for me to create a service to track my activity class and restart it after a crash? Note that i CANNOT use uncaughthandlers thread method to restart my app. My app is supposed to crash, don't worry about that part. My app is something simple, like this

```
private class AudioRenderer extends Activity {

private MediaPlayer AudioRenderer(String filePath) {
File location = new File(filePath);
        Uri path = Uri.fromFile(location);
  mp= MediaPlayer.create(this, path); 

}
return mp


}
```

Once this crashes, the service listening in the background will restart my app automatically. Anybody knows how this is possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that, yes, as explained below. But if **such techniques may make sense for experiments**, they are **definitely not suitable for production**. That would be awfully ugly and unefficient.

This said, here is a way to go:

- Make your `Service` [sticky](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY) or [redelivered](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_REDELIVER_INTENT) to ensure it will always be running after having been started once and not explicitely stopped.
- in your `Activity` class, statically store `WeakReference`s pointing to all its running instances and provide a way to statically check whether at least one of them is currently allocated:

  ```
  public class MyActivity extends Activity {
      private static ArrayList<WeakReference<MyActivity >> sMyInstances = new ArrayList<WeakReference<MyActivity >>();

      public MyActivity() {
          sMyInstances.add(new WeakReference<MyActivity >(this));            
      }

      private static int nbInstances() {
          int ret = 0;
          final int size = sMyInstances.size();

          for (int ctr = 0; ctr < size; ++ctr) {
              if (sMyInstances.get(ctr).get() != null) {
                  ret++; 
              }
          }

          return ret;
      }
  }
  ```

(`WeakReference` are references to objects that do not prevent these objects to be garbage-collected, more details [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_reference))

- Then, from your `Service`, call `MyActivity.nbInstances()` from time to time. It will return 0 a (usually short but theoretically unpredictable) while after the crash of the last running  `MyActivity` instance. **Warning**: it will do so unless you have a [memory leak](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/avoiding-memory-leaks.html) concerning this `Activity` or its underlying `Context` as this leak would prevent the garbage collection of the instance that crashed.
- Then you just have to start a new instance of your `Activity` from your `Service`, using `startActivity(Intent)`

Comment: Thanks, i will definitely try this out! But since you said this method would be ugly and  unefficient, do you know of a better way to restart my app once it crashes without using the thread exception handler?

Comment: Actually, the method itself is like this: restarting something that crashed instead of have this thing fixed is not nice, and is not efficient as the users sees a crash message, restart always takes some time, etc, etc. My comment was not related to that specific code.