# Duplicate MainActivity When Enter From Notification

Tags: android, android-activity

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(_context, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent activity = PendingIntent.getActivity(_context, 0, intent, 0);
    notification.contentIntent = activity;
```

Enter MainActivity from notification if MainActivity is already opened, thus I need exit twice. Is this a falg problem, what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes It is.. You have to add this flag to your pending Intent.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(_context, MainActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP|   Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
PendingIntent activity = PendingIntent.getActivity(_context, 0, intent, 0);
```

Taken form here,

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7308940/603744

Comment: OK, I got. Thx 4 quick reply.

Comment: Do some test, side effect found. Tow instance of activity launched, after add singleInstance then got solved.