# Restart the application when click on notification

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am using following code to open my application when clicking on Notification

```
mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                  context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);      

          PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
              i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);      

          NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
              new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
              .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
              .setContentTitle(title)
              .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
              .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                         .bigText(msg))
              .setContentText(msg);

         mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
         mNotificationManager.cancel(Constants.PUSH_ID);
         mNotificationManager.notify(Constants.PUSH_ID, mBuilder.build());
```

The problem is, if the application is already running, it opens startup application after my current activity.

```
 Intent x = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                                 i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                                 i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                                 i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

How can i close the old and start the application new one.

Comment: You need to use an appropriate intent filter in your Android Manifest.

Comment: basically you want to continue the app from where you left?

Comment: well, i want it to restart the app. Instead of creating new activities check my edited code for my Intent

Comment: I reckon starting the application from where you left it is a better approach.

Comment: well, ok but atleast it shouldn't start the activities over top of other activities. e.g if i am at activity 2 and i click on notification, it will start splash on top of activity 2 and so on. I have to go back to clear this stack

Comment: Yes, I'm also facing the same problem. It brings the triggered activity on top.

Comment: [Check this out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7308728/restart-application-on-notification-received?rq=1)

Comment: @Tushar i have already done this. My intent has all 3 set

Comment: Just use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` and not all.

Comment: Did you try just using FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP ?

Comment: @Tushar i found the solution, and no that flag didn't work either

Answer (score -2, accepted):

OK, i found a very cool and simple solution. I would just pass an extra boolean to my intent like `i.putExtra("shouldRestart", true);`

on my SplashActivity, i check

```
if(getIntent().getBooleanExtra("shouldRestart", false))
{
   // we need to clear all activities from top 
   finishAffinity();
}
```