# Crash Recovery android app

Tags: android, android-service

I'm developing an app and I want to put a crash recovery feature, restarting my app. I didn't write any code related to this.
My idea for this is to start a service that monitors the status. Base on this approach the problem is because service is start from my app, it'll die if app dies.
Is possible start a service from my app and runs it independently to monitor my app and restart it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to approach the problem you describe. Perhaps the simplest though is to provide a custom `Application` class for your project, and in its onCreate() method, call `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(this);` to assign your class as the default exception handler. That will require you to override `public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e)` which will be called at the time you crash, and you could schedule a restart.

If you really want something outside your process monitoring things, one approach is a service in your application that is defined to have its own process; this is done with an AndroidManifest attribute.

Another option is to use the Android AlarmManager, as that gets handled by the system and can restart your application.

Comment: AlarmManager I believe could be a solution if my app was scheduled. Using Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler I can use if I center in one place exception handling. Using a service for me is a good idea: I found this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7254720/how-to-restart-an-activity-automatically-after-it-crashes?rq=1) useful. But I really like to hear other approaches.

Comment: Use of the AlarmManager in your use case would be something like: when your app starts, you schedule an alarm with some delay. When that alarm fires, you verify the app is running (or restart it if needed), and also reschedule the next alarm. When your app terminates normally, you would remove the current alarm. This use case fits your unscheduled model by only starting when the app starts, and stopping (because you stop it) as soon as the app completes.

Answer (score -4):

You can start your service when phone boots by registering intent filter with action `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED`. More information can be found [here](http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/06/start-service-at-boot/) or in a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10853879/start-an-activity-on-phone-boot-in-android)

Comment: It is related to running service which will check status of application. Why AlarmManager is better then Service? And there might be more than one thread in application

Comment: I didn't say AlarmManager was better than a service, I said it's another option -- however since an application can crash without breaking the pending alarm, it is better. More importantly though, the question asked was not how to start such a service (which BOOT_COMPLETED is an answer to), but rather about the possibilities. Your answer assumes he wants something to start at device boot time, which he never stated. He only stated he wants app crash recovery; BOOT_COMPLETED suggests something which lives much longer than it should, wastes resources, and slows down people's phones.

Comment: Mah is right. I'll not start my service after boot completion. It starts just after my app starts. This is unnecessary because any other app will use the service, just mine.

Comment: Ok, you are right, I thought that an accent was on last sentence, 'how to start service'. I suggested 'BOOT_COMPLETED' only because using it service can be started independently of app and continue to run when it crashes.

Comment: Thanks marwinXXII for you reply too.